# Cancel button is not working properly in datepickerdialog in android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using datepicker dialog in my app in which i have set min and max date which is working fine. The set button sets the selected date in Edit text but the cancel button also works as set button and didn't return the previous save date.
Please some one help me in this.Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
private String dateToSave;
DatePickerDialog _date = null;

private DatePicker dpResult;

private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;

int minYear1 = 1970;
int minMonth1 = 0;//0-january , 1-february , 2-march..
int minDay1 =1;

int minYear = minYear1;
int minMonth = minMonth1;
int minDay = minDay1;

//these are the minimum dates to set Datepicker..
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;   

public String dateOutput=null;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_profile);
    dobET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dobET);

    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     mYear = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     mMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     mDay = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

     setCurrentDateOnView();

     dobET.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
                 showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
         }
 });

  public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    System.out.println("----------setCurrentDateOnView()-----------");



    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview


    // set current date into datepicker
    //dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
}


//this was the main part in program to Restrict the DatePicker Dialog  to only its current date.
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    System.out.println("----------onCreateDialog()-----------");


    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            _date =  new DatePickerDialog(this,  date,
                    year, mMonth, mDay){
       @Override
       public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
       {  
           System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"+mYear+"--"+year);
           System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"+mMonth+"--"+monthOfYear);
           System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"+mDay+"--"+dayOfMonth);

           myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
           myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
           myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);


          /* These lines of commented code used for only setting the maximum date on Date Picker..
           *
           * if (year > mYear && year)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

               if (monthOfYear > mMonth && year == mYear )
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

               if (dayOfMonth > mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);*/


           //these below lines of code used for setting the maximum as well as minimum dates on Date Picker Dialog..
           if (year < minYear)
               view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);

               if (monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear  )
               view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay );



               if (dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth)
               view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);


               if (year > mYear)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

               if (monthOfYear > mMonth && year == mYear)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

               if (dayOfMonth > mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

              dateOutput = String.format("Date Selected: %02d/%02d/%04d",
                                          dayOfMonth, monthOfYear+1, year);
              myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
              myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
              myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);


              updateLabel();
       }

   };     
    }
     return _date;
}
    private void updateLabel() {

    String myFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"; // In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);


    String myFormat2 = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat2, Locale.US);
    dateToSave = sdf2.format(myCalendar.getTime());
    saveDOBPrefEditor.putString("DOB", dateToSave);
    saveDOBPrefEditor.commit();

    dobET.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a code which displays the selected date on button (A date dialog is opend when you click this button and displays selected date on it).

Instead of the button, use editText.

The problem is with updateLabel(). you should not call inside onDateChange(). Because when you change the date, onDateChanged() method executes and even though you dont want to set the date and cancle the dialog, by that time  updateLable() will be called.

If the above doesnt work, try using the below code, which works fine for me.

```
private Button btnChangeDate;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//Date Button Instance
        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makepayact_btn_ChangeDate);

        //Date picker Dialog
        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();
}

// display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textView
        btnChangeDate.setText("Select");
    }

    //Button Listener
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makepayact_btn_ChangeDate);
        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            //getting current date instance
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int current_year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int current_month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int current_day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

// Cheque Date Validation -------> Keep or check your validations here 
            if(year<current_year || (year == current_year && month < current_month) || (month == current_month && year == current_year && day < current_day) ){

                //Display in a Dialog for Error
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomerMgmtActivity_MakePayment.this);
                //Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
                builder.setMessage("Cheque date should not be before today.")
                .setTitle("Cheque Date Error!");
                // Add the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK button
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                // Get the AlertDialog from create()
                AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
                alertdialog.show();

            }
            else{

                // set selected date into TextView
                btnChangeDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day)
                        .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));

                act_CheqDate = (new StringBuilder().append(year)
                        .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(day + 1)
                        .append(" ")).toString();
            }


        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because u have used updateLAbel() in the onDateChanged method and in your updateLabel() class, u have set the date in the textview. that means that everytime date is changed, updateLabel() is also executed and thus date is also set even if u have not pressed set button.
Solution: Define your own buttons Cancel and Set. Then setOnClickListener for Set button and move       dobET.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
this code there

Comment: can you elaborate how to do this?

Comment: ok.. lets start from ur question. As u said cancel button also sets the date, what exactly u mean by cancel button. U have not defined cancel button, so by cancel do u mean pressing back button?

Comment: ok... now look at your onDateChanged class. it is triggered everytime the date is changed in the dialog. u got upto this?

Comment: (y) mark the answer helpful if this solved ur problem ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63395/discussion-between-hirak-chhatbar-and-zohaib).